# Google drive clients to upload data to google drive not working in Centos 5

Tags: linux, centos, centos5, google-directory-api

I have been trying to setup a google drive client to upload my linux server data to google drive. I have used 'grive' and 'drive' on other machines that have Centos 6 versions and also ubuntu and those worked well. But none of this is working in Centos 5. Can any one please let me know any google drive client that is supported here. Already tried 'grive' and 'drive'. Thanks in advance.